# Successive approximation of unkown value

Tags: php, performance, loops, optimization, approximation

I have a url with a page system.

For instance https://myURL?p=50

But I want a script to find the last page available, for instance, let's say p=187

I have a function checkEmpty() that tells me whether the page is empty or not.
So for instance:

```php
$myUrl = new URL(50); //https://myURL?p=50
$myUrl->checkEmpty();
//This evaluates to false -> the page exists

$myUrl = new URL(188); //https://myURL?p=188
$myUrl->checkEmpty();
//This evaluates to true -> the page does NOT exist

$myUrl = new URL(187); //https://myURL?p=187
$myUrl->checkEmpty();
//This evaluates to false -> the page exists
```

I did a naive algorithm, that you might guess it, performs too much requests.

My question is:
What would be the algorithm to find the last page with the minimal amount of requests?

EDIT
As requested by people in the comment here is the checkEmpty() implementation

```php
<?php
public function checkEmpty() : bool
{
    $criteria = "Aucun contenu disponible";
    if(strstr( $this->replace_carriage_return(" ", $this->getHtml()), $criteria) !== false)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you storing the data about what pages exist? It would help a lot if we could see the current implementation of checkEmpty

Comment: Have you an idea of a theoretical maximum?  A hundred?  A thousand?  A million?  You might use a binary search within a scoped maximum

Comment: The answer is simple: binary search

Comment: If you don't have a theoretical maximum, you could use increasing powers of 2 until you find a page that doesn't exist, then do a binary search from there

Comment: @RobEyre let's say a 1000 tops!

Comment: We still can't really see the context. It looks like your URL class maybe loads some HTML from somewhere, but we don't know where. Is this content stored in a database perhaps?

Comment: You may need to show us more of the URL class, we could do with a [mre] of the issue. It's a bit unclear to me why you need to load the content, surely there's a better way to check if a page with the given ID already exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the upper bound is not known, exponentially increase the page no by 2 starting from 1. The moment you hit a non-existent page, you can do a [`binary search`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) from previous existing page + 1 till this new upper bound where the page doesn't exist.

This way, you can get your answer in `O(log(n))` attempts asymptotically where `n` is the no. of existing pages here as the sample space.

```
<?php

$lowerBound = 1;
$upperBound = 1;

while(true){
    $myUrl = new URL($upperBound);
    if($myUrl->checkEmpty()){
        break;
    }
    $lowerBound = $upperBound + 1;
    $upperBound <<= 1;
}

$ans = $lowerBound;

while($lowerBound <= $upperBound){
    $mid = $lowerBound + (($upperBound - $lowerBound) >> 1);
    $myUrl = new URL($mid);
    if($myUrl->checkEmpty()){
        $upperBound = $mid - 1;
    }else{
        $lowerBound = $mid + 1;
        $ans = $lowerBound;
    }
}

echo $ans;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer.
It does solve my problem :)
And computes a little faster than my naive implementation!

Comment: @MrJay42 Glad to point you in the right direction. It should compute way faster than usual iterative one. Network call could be the bottleneck providing only a little better performance than the iterative approach.

Comment: Indeed the network is the bottleneck, but it would be regardless of the implementation. The code you suggested definitely optimizes the amount of calls, at least compared to my original naive implementation.